# Active objects and LocalDate

Tags: java, jira-plugin, active-objects

I am trying to create AO Object with a field of type java.time.LocalDate in JIRA plugin. Ao Object has not been created. If I change type оf field to  java.util.Date, AO object creates. Log has not any errors. Is it possible to have AO Object with java.time.LocalDate  field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

[Refer the table under the Type Changes section.](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/ao-0-18-x-upgrade-guide/) To see all the Java Types supported by Active Objects.